# Server error while playing a video: HTTP Error 404.3

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2010, html, video, iframe

i have an application where i require to upload a video as:

html

```
<iframe id="frame1" runat="server" visible="false"
       style="height: 222px; width: 482px;"></iframe>
```

Code

```
Finalpath = filepath + filename;
frame1.Visible = true;
frame1.Attributes.Add("src", Finalpath);
```

but when i load the video Extension `Mp4` it shows the error in `Iframe`

```
HTTP Error 404.3 - Not Found
```

The page you are requesting cannot be served because of the extension configuration. If the page is a script, add a handler. If the file should be downloaded, add a MIME map.

how to handle this Server Error and what type(extension) of video i can upload? thanks for any assistance..

Comment: You should add MIME type for .MP4 format on IIS or in web.config file

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You should add MIME type for .MP4 format on IIS or in web.config file
In Web.Config For IIS 7 you can add this section in configuration.

```
<system.webServer>
    <staticContent>
        <mimeMap fileExtension=".mp4" mimeType="video/mp4" />
    </staticContent>
</system.webServer>
```

You can use HTML 5 `<video>` tag to display your .mp4 video

```
<video width="320" height="240" controls="controls">
  <source src="movie.mp4" type="video/mp4">
  Your browser does not support the video tag.
</video>
```

Comment: YEah it works now. but i have a .mp4 file. instead of in the frame. the pop up comes and it playes in default window media player.. how to play in the same Iframe????

Comment: Yes you can. Try to make source as runat="server" give an id.

Comment: what about the object tag for html. how can we use that any idea??

Comment: You can use <Object> tag. But to display .MP4 video, it is required a quick time activeX control for the browser.

Comment: okay. asp.net is not supporting the video tag. i am finding the error while working.

Comment: <Video> Tag is new in HTML 5, If you are using VS 2010, It will not display any intellisence for it. but you can use it in your aspx markup file. But to run your browser must support html5.